# App hangs when LiveData is assigned null value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have a LiveData named navigationArgs:

```
private val _navigationArgs = MutableLiveData<Item>()
val navigationArgs: LiveData<Item>; get() = _navigationArgs
```

which stores the arguments to be passed to the next fragment. It is attached to an observer, to navigate when the value is changed:

```
viewModel.navigationArgs.observe(this, Observer{
 //navigation code
 viewModel.finishedNavigating()
})
```

in which in finishedNavigating(), value of _navigationArgs is set to null:

```
fun finishedNavigating(){
 _navigationArgs.value = null
}
```

When `finishedNavigating()` is included in the observer, the app hangs without even navigating, when the `_navigationArgs` value is changed.

Why does this happen? I am using Android Studio 4.0 Canary. Thank you.

Comment: if (it != null) viewModel.finishedNavigating() Try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assigning something to `_navigationArgs.value`, code will be automatically called in Observer, that used in `viewModel.navigationArgs.observe` (`navigationArgs` and `_navigationArgs` are same objects because `navigationArgs` has getter, that returns `_navigationArgs` ).

In your case you assigning `null` to `_navigationArgs.value` in `finishedNavigating()`, which calls code in `Observer`, which calls `finishedNavigating()` again etc...

You just have recursion here.

You should add recursion exit condition. For example:

```
viewModel.navigationArgs.observe(this, Observer{
 //navigation code
 if (it != null) //don't call finishedNavigating, when null passed in to _navigationArgs.value
  viewModel.finishedNavigating()
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution worked. I surrounded the navigation code and the ```finishedNavigating()``` in ```it?.let{...}``` instead.

Comment: I think we should not be doing computation inside the Observer. It should be a ViewModel responsibility to handle the null check and pass the value accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but the navigation code includes the navigation arguments passed to the next fragment, and if a null check wasn't done in the Observer, then an error will be thrown as ```null``` would be passed to the navigation code arguments, in which ```Item``` is expected.

Answer (score 1):

mmm, it looks like an endless loop of values sent to the observer, every time you set a value null is sent and then again and again.